# Bulk Update in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to update multiple documents in RethinkDB, based on some precalculated values in a Hash. i.e.

Given a table `stats` with primary key `slug` with data like

```
[{slug: 'foo', stats: {}}, {slug:'bar', stats:{}}]
```

and given a Hash with values like

```
updated_stats = {
  'foo' => {a: 1, b: 2}, 
  'bar' => {a: 3, b: 4}
}
```

I can do this

```
updated_stats.each{|k,v| 
  r.table('stats').get(k).update{|s| 
    { :stats => v } 
  }  
}
```

So, why can't I do the following?

```
r.table('stats').get_all(*updated_stats.keys).update{|s| 
  { :stats => updated_stats[s["slug"]] }  
}
```

the rql shows nil as the value of updated_stats[s["slug"]]. Would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a tricky problem.

Here's the solution first.

```
r.table('stats').get_all(*updated_stats.keys).update{|s| 
  { :stats => r.expr(updated_stats).get_field(s["slug"]) } 
}.run()
```

Then `updated_stats` is a ruby hash so when you use the brackets, it's the usual bracket operator, and since `updated_stats` doesn't have the key s["slug"], it returns nil.
So you have to wrap `updated_stats` in `r.expr()`.

Then brackets in ruby are used for `nth`, `get_field`, `slice` etc. And when given a variable, it cannot guess which one it should use.
So you have to explicitly say you want to use `get_field`.
We will add a bracket term, which should fix this problem -- see https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1179

Sorry you ran into this!

Comment: This is in JavaScript with rethinkdbdash. Pass the connection if you are using the official driver.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for how to bulk update records, it's actually pretty easy but not at all intuitive.

You actually have to perform an `insert` while specifying that if there's any conflicts, to update those records. You will obviously need to provide the Id of each record to be updated.

Using the following data set:

```
|-------------|--------------|
|      id     |     title    |
|-------------|--------------|
|      1      |      fun     |
|-------------|--------------|
|      2      |      in      |
|-------------|--------------|
|      3      |      the     |
|-------------|--------------|
|      4      |      sun     |
|-------------|--------------|
```

Here's an example (javascript):

```
const new_data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'dancing'},
    {id: 4, title: 'rain'},
];

r.db('your_db').table('your_table').insert(new_data, {conflict: 'update'});
```

The results would be:

```
|-------------|--------------|
|      id     |     title    |
|-------------|--------------|
|      1      |    dancing   |
|-------------|--------------|
|      2      |      in      |
|-------------|--------------|
|      3      |      the     |
|-------------|--------------|
|      4      |      rain    |
|-------------|--------------|
```

One caveat you should be aware of, though, is that if you represent something in the `new_data` array that doesn't currently exist in the table, *it will be added/upserted*.

Cheers!

Comment: Aww, you saved my life! That's what I've been looking for. It's not explicitly defined in the official documents, unfortunately..